# Enable/Disable USB Interface in Powershell

Tags: javascript, powershell, scripting, electron

I'm developing an application with electronjs, and I need to enable/disable USB mounting on my computer.

I have in main.js :

```js
function monitoring() {
    usbDetect.startMonitoring();
    usbDetect.on('add', function(device) {
        createWindow();
        PowerShell.$`reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\USBSTOR /v start /t REG_DWORD /d 4 /f`;
    });
}
```

I have a `close3()` function in my created window:

```js
function close3() {
    window.close();
    PowerShell.$`reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\USBSTOR /v start /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f`;
}
```

The problem is that my USB interface does not refresh after allowing the USB plug in, and my partition is not mounted. I have already searched without finding a solution.

I saw there is a solution with devcon.exe but I have to use **CLI only**.

Thanks.

Comment: There are now the `Enable-PnpDevice` and `Disable-PnpDevice` commands available - have you tried them? e.g. `Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object { $_.FriendlyName -match 'USB Enhanced Host Controller' } | ForEach-Object {  $_  | Disable-PnpDevice }`

Comment: I've tried them, but I haven't to specify a usb key ID, and it supposed to block any usb key